# jquery , i want to stop dragging div , when div's position is on specific point without draggable ui

Tags: jquery, drag

i want to stop dragging div , when div's position is on specific point without draggable ui

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.8.3.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x;

    var mdown = false;
    $("#mydrag1").bind("mousedown",function(e){
        mdown = true;
        x = e.clientX;      
    });


    $(document).bind("mousemove",function(e){
        if(mdown){
            var gx = e.clientX - x;

            var posX = e.clientX - e.offsetX;
            console.log("posX:" + posX);
            if(posX < 500){//I want mydrag1's  dragging is stop when mydrag1's x-position is 500
                $("#mydrag1").css("left",parseInt($("#mydrag1").css("left"),10) + gx + "px");
            }
            x = e.clientX;

        }
    });

    $(document).bind("mouseup",function(e){
        mdown = false;
    });

});
</script>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<div id="mydrag1" style="position:absolute;left:100px;top:200px;width:200px;height:100px;background:gold">
MY DRAG1
</div>
```

I want that mydrag1's  dragging is stop , when mydrag1's x-position is 500
but mydrag1 is still draggable over 500

sorry , my english is poor

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind("mousemove",function(e){
    if(mdown){
        var gx = e.clientX - x;

        var posX = e.clientX;

        if(posX < 500){
            $("#mydrag1").css("left",parseInt($("#mydrag1").css("left"),10) + gx + "px");
        }
        x = e.clientX;
    }
});
```

Comment: I try your code, but when mouseup and retry to mousedown  and retry to drag  , still draggable  as changing  click point inside div

Comment: and i want that div's right direction dragging is disable, but div's left direction dragging is enable when div's x-position is 500

Comment: @subzero - 'if(posX < 500)' to 'if (posX < 500 || $('mydrag1').offset().left < 500)'